# Numerical computation of continuous Fourier transform

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-analysis

Are there any algorithms that numerically compute the continuos Fourier transform of a given function f?
I find plenty of implementations of the discrete Fourier transform, using FFT,
but, if I´m not mistaken, DFT is not a discrete approximation of the continuous Fourier transform, but a different, although related, concept.

Comment: The GSL has oscillatory integration schemes that do the integration. You could do the integration with any quadrature of your choosing, really.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fast Fourier transform (FFT) **is used** to compute numerical approximations to continuous Fourier transforms (CFT). This is not apart from its application or correspondence to Discrete Fourier of course. A numerical approximation of the CFT requires evaluating a large number of integrals, each with a different integrand, since the values of this integral for a large range of the *variable* are needed. The FFT can be effectively applied to this problem. There are however cases where FFT in brotherhood with DFT are not accurate; e.g. DFT is periodical and spectrum aliasing may occur, other approximations are elaboreted on the spot such as [here>>>](http://www.risc.jku.at/conferences/snsc01/beauchemin.pdf)

See further
[Here>>>](http://www.davidhbailey.com/dhbpapers/fourint.pdf)
[Here>>>](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/NumericalApproximationOfTheFourierTransformByTheFastFourierT/)

Also cross reference
[Here>>>](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388009/numerical-approximation-of-the-continuous-fourier-transform)