# how to use Matlab ifft to calculate the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, matlab

$$R(t)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty\dfrac{\omega e^{i\omega t}}{(3-\omega^2)^{2}+4\omega^2}\,d\omega$$

where t is a integer and $t>0$

I used to calculate this integral by numerical integral,but it seems that using ifft in matlab is more effcient.

The ifft equation in Matlab is $$x(n)=\frac{1}{N}\sum_{k=1}^N X(k)e^{i2\pi\frac{k-1}{N}n-1}$$  where n=$1,2...,N$

I have no idea how to link the above Eq with the above-mentioned integral. Do someone have an idea?

Comment: Is there any specific reason why you think there could be a connection?

Comment: @knedlsepp Both the eq of ifft and R(t) have a similar term e^(iwt), so I think it might be possible to calculate R(t) by ifft. By the way, I have found a link which stated a similar question.[link](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388009/numerical-approximation-of-the-continuous-fourier-transform)