# Solution to a particular second order differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Consider that we have the following forced vibration **with an input frequency $ω(t)$ variable in time.** 
$$m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx = F_0 \sin{(\omega(t) t)}$$

Assuming that the solution must be a harmonic form but with lag some **phase angle $ψ$** we consider a solution to be:

$$x(t)=X_0 \sin{(\omega(t) t-ψ)}$$

**Firstly, Is it true that the lag phase $ψ$ is also variable with time and so the particular solution must be as follows?** $$x(t)=X_0 \sin{(\omega(t) t-ψ(t))}$$

**Secondly, If the first question holds, how is the general solution formulated because the calculations gets really complicated?**

Comment: Is there something special about $\omega(t)$? Why don't you simply write $\Omega(t)$ instead of  $\omega(t)t$ or even instead of $\sin(\omega(t)t)$?

Comment: Nothing special about it, you can take it as Ω(t).

Comment: In terms of the homogeneous solution, much depends on the sign of $c^2-4km,$ the discriminant of the characteristic polynomial. As for the general solution, the problem is not solvable without knowing $\omega(t).$ Do you know $\omega(t)?$ I would definitely guess that the phase angle would be dependent on time, as the phase angle is essentially equivalent to having a cosine term (a more usual ansatz for your solution than merely sine).

Comment: Yes, ω(t) is a known function, but the solution gets to tricky to find. Have any idea?

Comment: If you know what $\omega(t)$ is, can you please write that out in the question?

Comment: In my application it is ω(t)=t/(1+t^2)^1/2, but you can take a simpler one. lets say ω(t)=t.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Consider the general equation: 
$$
m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx =F_0(t)\tag1
$$
and let $x(\omega,t)$ be the particular solution of:
$$m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx =e^{i\omega t}.\tag2$$

Then the particular solution of $(1)$ can be computed as:
$$
x(t) = \int_{-\infty}^\infty F_0(\omega)x(\omega,t)d\omega,
$$
where
$$
F_0(\omega)=\int_{-\infty}^\infty F_0(t)e^{-i\omega t}dt
$$
is the Fourier transform of $F_0(t)$.

Comment: the ω you use is ω(t)?

Comment: @VaggelisKyrilas No. I replaced your equation with $(1)$. $\omega$ is just an auxilarily variable, which while solving (2) shall be considered as a constant . If you know something about Fourier transform, you see that it is a value complementary to $t$, i.e. frequency assuming that $t$ is time.

Comment: So the solution x(t) is the general solution of the differential or it is the particular one?

Comment: @VaggelisKyrilas It is the particular solution. At the end you should add it to the general solution of $m\ddot{x}+c\dot{x}+kx =0$ and find the corresponding integration constants from initial conditions.

Comment: Things gets hard again trying to solve the integral of $Fo(ω)$ which is the integral of the function $sin(f(t))*e^{-iωt}$

Comment: Surely the integral can be evaluated in a closed form not for every $f(t)$. It can be however helpful to represent it as $\operatorname{Im}\int e^{i(f(t)-\omega)t}dt$. The point is that is much simpler to analyze the behavior of the integral than that of the solution of the corresponding ODE. And in any case you can evaluate the integral numerically for every value of $\omega$ in the range your are interested in.

Comment: Can you give or direct to an analogous numerical calculation?

Comment: There are a lot of information on the topic here. For example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/388009/numerical-approximation-of-the-continuous-fourier-transform.